# Wizard-like layering of different panels or different form windows for each view/panel?

Tags: .net, winforms, panel, desktop-application, wizard

I have to make panels to view different tasks/activities in my application. Now, I just need a suggestion about which technique is preferable, making layers of panels on each other like a wizard or simply make different form windows for each panel?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different options to satisfy such requirement.
As an option you can implement a tabbed window:

- Use a `TabControl` that will host different forms in each `TabPage`
- For each view you need to show in tabbed window, Create a `Form`, set form's `TopLevel` property to `false`, Set `BorderStyle` to `None`
- When you want to show a form, Add a `TabPage` to your `TabControl` and then add form to `TabPage` and then `Show` form

Comment: I already know the working of TabControl. But I don't wanna use them. Because I need wizard-like functionality (like navigating from page to page just like an install wizard). Some suggest a workaround hiding tabs at run-time keeping them visible in designer. But that's not a good idea IMO because tabs stills reserve their space, they only become hidden. Why would someone use tabs with hidden tab heading when their is a better solution to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. Actually I was waiting for some other answers.

Comment: @user3357779 My offer is a tabbed window like for example IE. anyway you can use wizard controls. Search for "windows forms wizard control" and take a look at codeplex and codeproject results. hope you find it helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a `UserControl` for each panel.

**Pros:**

- It is much easier to maintain the parent form because the UserControl
  is independent of the parent form.
- You can't accidentally change the layout while moving them around the
  parent form.
- You can keep the code for that panel separate from the parent form's code.

(There are other benefits, but my brain appears to have stopped.)

**Cons:**

- It takes a little bit more code to do, as you will need to add public
  properties to the UserControl so that the information it contains is
  accessible to the parent form.